# how to immediately render component after making changes in database

Tags: node.js, reactjs, mongodb

I have created a page where user will see some products. every products has a delivered button. if user click on delivered button the products quantity will decrease by 1. then it will immediately render the component and show new quantity

Comment: You need to show your code what you have done .

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm using a state to set products. Let's say there is a quantity and distructuring quantity

```
const [product, setProduct] = useState({});
const { quantity} = product;
```

I'm setting up a function that decrease that quantity by one

```
function removeOne() {
        let newQuantity = quantity - 1;
        const newProduct = { ...product, quantity: newQuantity }
        //copy all previous data if exist in product and setup new quantity 
        setProduct(newProduct);
        fetch(`your server link/${id}`, {
            method: 'PUT',
            headers: {
                'Content-Type': 'application/json'
            },
            body: JSON.stringify(newProduct)
        })
    }

<button onClick={() => removeOne(id)}}>Button</button>
```